# How does com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4 work for multiple networks?

Tags: docker, networking, ip-address

The [documentation for the bridge network driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/#options) says:

> `com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4` `--ip`  Default IP when binding container ports

Since containers can belong to one or more networks, but there is only one host, how is applied in the case of a container with multiple networks?